# Retrieving file via Ubuntu One API brings back webpage

Tags: ubuntu-one, ubuntu-one-api

I'm playing around with the Ubuntu One API (coding in Java) and can successfully make calls using:

GET /api/file_storage/v1

and

GET /api/file_storage/v1/~/path/to/volume/path/to/node

to get information about the directory structure and files.

When I make a GET request for:

https://files.one.ubuntu.com/YgLpi504etc.etc.etc.

I get a webpage back (works in a browser obviously, but not in my code):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>OpenID transaction in progress</title>
    </head>
    <body onload="document.forms[0].submit();">
        <form id="openid_message" action="https://login.launchpad.net/+openid" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"><input type="hidden" name="openid.return_to" value="https://files.one.ubuntu.com/auth/complete/?next=%2FYgLpi504SI6eOmbTtQuRWw%2F&amp;janrain_nonce=2012-01-10T23%3A20%3A10ZjM6Ttj"/><input type="hidden" name="openid.realm" value="https://files.one.ubuntu.com/"/><input type="hidden" name="openid.ns" value="http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0"/><input type="hidden" name="openid.sreg.optional" value="email,fullname,nickname"/><input type="hidden" name="openid.claimed_id" value="http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select"/><input type="hidden" name="openid.ns.sreg" value="http://openid.net/extensions/sreg/1.1"/><input type="hidden" name="openid.assoc_handle" value="{HMAC-SHA1}{4efc9f73}{E6WEdg==}"/><input type="hidden" name="openid.mode" value="checkid_setup"/><input type="hidden" name="openid.identity" value="http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select"/><input type="submit" value="Continue"/>
    </form>
        <script>
            var elements = document.forms[0].elements;
            for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                elements[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is this the wrong URL to be using in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to fetch the file content, you need to use https://files.one.ubuntu.com/ + `content_path` URL, the links that are used for https://one.ubuntu.com/files/ will not work with OAuth.